# What image slideshow applications have many transition effects?

Tags: software-recommendation, slideshow

Is there any good application for image slideshows that has many transition effects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried `Shotwell` (it is default in Ubuntu)?

And there is `F-spot Photo Manager`  [Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/f-spot) 
[image]

> F-Spot is a full-featured personal photo management application for the GNOME desktop. It simplifies digital photography by providing intuitive tools to help you share, touch-up, find and organize your images. It allows for importing of your existing photo collections, tagging photos with identifiers, as well as doing simple edits of photos (e.g. rotating).

And There is `Picasa` : [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/linux/) 
Very well known and great image Application.
Picasa slide show:[image]

Comment: The link for Picasa is broken, as Google is no longer supporting it.

Comment: No longer supporting on Linux (see [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/google-officially-drop-picasa-for-linux)). Alternatives [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137491/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-picasa). You should also be able to run it under Wine - the stuff [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-picasa-39-in-linux-and-fix.html) may help there.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Imagination](http://imagination.sourceforge.net/).  Its a DVD slide show maker featuring 69 transitions. 
I installed it from [GetDeb.net](http://www.getdeb.net/software/Imagination).

Comment: Nice one! Was gonna suggest it myself :)!

Answer (score 0):

For *Ubuntu* (or *Linux, in general*) there are:

- [OpenShot Video Editor](https://www.openshot.org/)
- [Imagination](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imagination/) video editor
- [PhotoFilmStrip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/photostoryx/)
- [Avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:create_video_from_still_image_and_from_audio_file)

And others. You can get *ALL* of them if you install a *Linux* distribution called "*ARTISTX*" (Version 1.5 liveDVD download from developer site).

There are a good number of transitions and they are VISUAL so no need deep knowledge of *Linux* or the use of command line. Pay special attention to *OpenShot Video Editor* and *Imagination*.This last one is FRAGILE but I am sure you will manage it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! Note I think you can install all of those packages on Ubuntu, you don't need to install another distro (which looks like a Ubuntu derivative anyway). Also most of these seem to be video editors, which aren't just there to make image slideshows...

Comment: Of course you can install such programs one by one! But, if you wish various programs to make your videos and slide shows its better to install ARTISTX and is IS
an UBUNTU variant! IMAGINATION IS a SLIDE SHOW program with a varity of transitions
and VERY EASY do operate! But, as NOTHING is perfect it is FRAGILE!But, I am sure
you (or anybody) can manage it all right!