# Picasa ? An alternative

Tags: google-picasa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best alternative to Picasa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137491/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-picasa)

is there a recommened alternative to Picasa for an amateur such as myself. I used and liked Picasa immensely on my old windows and now that it is not available for ubuntu i would like to know if a good alternative exists
Thanks 
Simon

Comment: See also: [How would I install Picasa 3.9?](http://askubuntu.com/q/86452/866)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9 you can still install and use Picasa in Linux without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Shotwell is a default on Ubuntu I believe and it works very good.  No errors and the tagging system is drag and drop.

Not sure if it will import your picassa library, but if the meta data is written to the picture files it should do it no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shotwell (mentioned by @Goddard) is a great replacement alternative for Picasa. Anyway you may miss some useful tools from Picasa.

This question has been asked before and I am not sure if you are referring to a new version of Picasa but as far as we can say, Picasa 3.9 can be installed by using [this workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/139842/9598).

I provide you with some screenshots of Picasa running in my Desktop via Wine (remember, Picasa won't run native in Ubuntu but you can run it via Wine which needs to be previously installed).

[image]
Starting Picasa

[image]
Picasa Running

May I also suggest you to take a look in Software Center and run a search for "Picasa" (without quotation marks) and you will be provided with some alternatives from the official repositories as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

Additionally, please consider to tell us which version of Ubuntu you are running in order to provide you with further details.

They have already started closing your question. so...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try Digikam to administer you images, it has loads of features and you can export to Picasa.

> digiKam is an advanced digital photo management application for Linux, Windows, and Mac-OSX.

**Export Screenshot**

[image: Export Options]

If want to give it a try open up your **Ubuntu Software Center** and search for **digikam** and as you can see below its gets nearly 5 stars from 51 reviews.

[image: Digikam rating]

Reference Links:

http://www.digikam.org/