# How to install Picasa Picture Viewer on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, picasa

I need to install Google Picasa picture Viewer on ubuntu 12.04 but there is no such package for Ubuntu or any other Linux distro.

Comment: This is not intended to answer your question but based on the answers you have received so far, this link may be useful  http://askubuntu.com/questions/137491/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-picasa

Answer (score 1):

Even when it was supported by Google, what they distributed was just the windows executable and a copy of wine. This combination still works.

Install `wine` from the software center (or with `sudo apt-get install wine`).

Download the latest [installer](http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe) and then run it by double clicking in `nautilus` or running `wine picasa39-setup.exe` in a terminal. This should take you through the install process and add an entry to the applications menu.

Being a windows application, it doesn't integrate that well with Ubuntu. I have found picasa 3.9 to crash occasionally in Ubuntu - anecdotally earlier versions (3.6) may be more reliable.

While it is likely to be possible to run picasa for windows under wine for the foreseeable future, you may wish to consider using a native application, such as `shotwell`.

Comment: More detail given by http://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasa as a web based application without installing anything, have a look at this link :
[Picasa Web](https://picasaweb.google.com/home)

You may also want to look at the answer to this question on [Installing Picasa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9).

Comment: Means when I have to immediately view a picture First I have to Upload then view it in browser NOT A GOOD IDEA

Comment: I use picasa web for backing up & sharing photos with friends/family, but I use Shotwell or Gimp for viewing & editing photos because they are better in my opinion. Hope my answer helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Good officially killed support for the Picasa Linux client back in April, 2012. Your best option is to use [Picasa Web](https://picasaweb.google.com/home) or you can use one of the many photo management apps that are available for Linux such as shotwell